# Spark: udf to get dirname from path

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have insane amount of path columns I need to split in 2 columns, basename and dirname. I know how to get easily the basename of my paths using :

```
val df = Seq("/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file"
    ,"/test/jambon/test")
    .toDF("column1")
df.withColumn("basename", substring_index($"column1"  , "/", -1))
.show(2, false)
+------------------------------+---------+
|column1                       |basename |
+------------------------------+---------+
|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file|file     |
|/test/jambon/test             |test     |
+------------------------------+---------+
```

However I'm strugling to get the dirname like this :

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
|column1                       |dirname                   |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file|/test/coucou/jambon/hello |
|/test/jambon/test             |/test/jambon              |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I have tried various solution however I'm unable to find a functional columnar solution.
My best idea would be to subtract `$"basename"` to `$"column1"`, however I couldn't find a way to subtract String in Spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expr to substring the column1. The code should look like below. I hope its helpful.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq("/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file"
  ,"/test/jambon/prout/test")
  .toDF("column1")

val test = df.withColumn("basename", substring_index($"column1"  , "/", -1))
    .withColumn("path", expr("substring(column1, 1, length(column1)-length(basename)-1)"))

test.show(false)
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|column1                       |basename|path                     |
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file|file    |/test/coucou/jambon/hello|
|/test/jambon/prout/test       |test    |/test/jambon/prout       |
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: looks interesting, though I wish they were an easier way :D It's over complicated for IMO something that should be way easier .... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well after putting more thoughts in it. it seems to be the only way to handle short path such as `/filex.txt` by keeping the last `/` (remove the -1 in substring)

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative approach to already provided solution using Regular expression**

Get your regular expression right. ***regexp_extract*** UDF will give you what you wanted.

```
   val df = Seq("/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file"
      , "/test/jambon/prout/test")
      .toDF("column1")

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

    df.withColumn("path", regexp_extract('column1, "^\\/(\\w+\\/)+", 0)).withColumn("fileName",regexp_extract('column1, "\\w+$", 0)).show(false)
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+
|column1                       |path                      |fileName|
+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+
|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/|file    |
|/test/jambon/prout/test       |/test/jambon/prout/       |test    |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+--------+
```

**Edit:**
Without trailing slash regex is easier to manage:

```
df.withColumn("path",regexp_extract($"column1", "^(.+)(/.+)$", 1 ) ) )
```

Comment: doesn't work when using a shorter path such as: `/file.txt` column path is empty and should be IMO a `/`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use UDFs:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val pathUDF = udf((s: String) => s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/")))

val test = df.withColumn("basename", substring_index($"column1"  , "/", -1))
    .withColumn("path", pathUDF($"column1"))

test.show(false)
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|column1                       |basename|path                     |
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|/test/coucou/jambon/hello/file|file    |/test/coucou/jambon/hello|
|/test/jambon/prout/test       |test    |/test/jambon/prout       |
+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: doesn't work when using a shorter path such as: /file.txt column path is empty and should be IMO a /